# No write permission when installing packages

Tags: r, installation

I'm trying to install some packages in a non-default library location, but I'm getting errors that seem to be connected to lack of write permissions in that location:

```
withr::with_libpaths('app/library', devtools::install_local('MYPACKAGE'))
## ERROR: failed to create lock directory 'XXXXXXXXXX'
## Warning in dir.create(lockdir, recursive = TRUE) :
##   cannot create dir 'YYYYYYYYYY', reason 'Permission denied'

withr::with_libpaths('app/library', devtools::install_local('WWWWWWWWW', args = '--no-lock'))
## ERROR: unable to create 'app/library/MYPACKAGE'

dir.create('app/library/MYPACKAGE')
withr::with_libpaths('app/library', devtools::install_local('MYPACKAGE', args = '--no-lock'))
## Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
##   cannot create file '/app/library/MYPACKAGE/libs/i386', reason 'No such file or directory'
## Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
##   cannot create file '/app/library/MYPACKAGE/libs/x64', reason 'No such file or directory'
## Error in file.copy(files, file.path(instdir, "exec"), TRUE) : 
##   more 'from' files than 'to' files
```

As the third chunk attempt there suggests, it's not as though I don't have write permissions to the 'app/library' location. I can create files and directories with the `file.create` and `dir.create` commands just fine. But it seems I'm fighting a hydra: every time I manually create one necessary directory, the package installation process shows me it needs two more.

Why can't R use my write permissions when installing? Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: It might have to do with `dir.create` expanding the current working directory.  Take a look at `getwd()` and `.libPaths()` to see if any changes to your code are needed.

Comment: @manotheshark Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. `getwd()` and `.libPaths()` both return the values I expected them to have. What changes might I need to make to them?

Comment: I am not acuainted with `withr`, but does `with_libpaths` require absolute path? That may be the reason. From the output it seem to be looking for the directory starting from the root  ( `/app/` instead of  something like `/home/username/app/` in linux parlance)

Comment: @R.S. I get the same error using an absolute path - the error just references the absolute path instead. It doesn't seem like relative filepaths are the problem.